# How to pass values to form

Tags: magnific-popup

I am using magnify-popup to display a form. I want to pass some values to this form. How could I do this.I could not find this in documentation.

```
$('#rangeBtn').magnificPopup({
    items: {
        src: '#rangeFormDiv',
        type: 'inline'
    }

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could probably grab the form in a callback and then insert values into the form.

So it might look something along the lines of:

```
$('#rangeBtn').magnificPopup({
    items: {
        src: '#rangeFormDiv',
        type: 'inline'
    },
    callbacks: {
         beforeOpen: function() {
             // Your logic here
         }
    }
 });
```

For more information, check out the [API page](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api).

Answer (score 1):

**Sample rangeFormDiv:**

```
<div id="rangeFormDiv">
  <form>
    <input type="text name="var1" value="">
    <input type="text name="var2" value="">
    <input type="text name="var3" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="save">
  </form>
</div>
```

**Anchor:**

```
<a href="#rangeFormDiv" data-variable="some content" class="magnificPopup">Open</a>
```

**magnificPopup initialize:**

```
$('.magnificPopup').magnificPopup({
    type: 'inline',

    fixedContentPos: false,
    fixedBgPos: true,

    overflowY: 'auto',

    closeBtnInside: true,
    preloader: false,

    midClick: true,
    removalDelay: 300,
    mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in',
    modal: true,
    //define variable before open
    //target element: $($(this.items).attr('href'))
    //anchor: $(this.items)
    callbacks: {
        beforeOpen: function(){
            $($(this.items).attr('href')).find('input[name="var1"]').val($(this.items).data("variable"));
        }
    }
});
```